# ifstream variable not reading correct character 1

Tags: c++, boolean, ifstream

I have an issue with the following code snippet.

I have a file referred to with the character array `FileName`. The file could be basically anything, but in my case it is a file the contains some irrelevant text on the first line and then some lines that start with 1 (one) in one case and 0 (zero) in many other cases. So, my file is something like:

```
iewbFLUW 82494HJF VROIREBURV.TEXT

0 TEST whatever something
0 TEST words and more
1 TEST something something
0 TEST oefeowif
...
```

The intention of the my code snippet is that it picks the line selected with 1 (one).

```
// the stream object for my file:
string FileName = "myFile.text";
ifstream input(FileName);

// parsing the first line
char comment[1000];
input.getline(comment, 1000, '\n');
cout << comment << endl;

// parsing the other lines
bool select=false;
while (!input.eof())
{
    input >> select;

    cout << select << endl;
    if(select){
    // do something
     }
}
```

However, although the `FileName` starts the second line with a 0 (zero), the variable `select` turns out to have value 1 right after the line `input >> select;`

How can this be?

Comment: Please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Using `while (!input.eof())` is wrong. Use `while (input >> select)` instead.

Comment: What do you mean by 0(zero)? An ascii or binary value?

Comment: @NathanOliver: I just did. Hope this helps...

Comment: As you're attempting to extract a `bool` from an input stream, I'm curious how you perceive anything *besides* `1` or `0` being read, because that is exactly what will fail with your while-loop as-presented here.

Comment: @WhozCraig yes that is of course true, and that is being taken care of. Sorry this is just a very small piece of a much larger project, and I forgot to include the code dealing with the rest of the line(s). My bad. My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The major problem with your code is that `input >> select` **does not read a full line**, but it stops at the first whitespace. You then read again what you believe is a `bool` from the next line, but which in fact is the next character from the first word in the line, so your stream ends up with a `failbit` set, and after that it's game over, you cannot successfully read from the stream again.

Read the whole line instead and use a `std::stringstream` to parse it, like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    string FileName = "test.txt";
    ifstream input(FileName);

    // parsing the first line
    std::string line;
    getline(input, line); // ignore first line
    bool select = false;
    while (getline(input, line)) // read line by line
    {
        std::istringstream ss(line); // map back to a stringstream
        ss >> select; // extract the bool
        if (select) { // process the line (or the remaining stringstream)
            cout << line; // display the line if it select == true
        }
    }
}
```

As mentioned in the comments, `while(!input.eof())` is almost always wrong, see [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/3093378)

Comment: I was going to post an example with mixed operator >> and getline and ignore, but it's basically the same.  I just avoid constructing stringstreams and avoid reading the ignored lines into memory.